# Trying to make my Discord Bot repeatedly generate answers without looping message, chooseanswer is undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

For my 8ball command, I am trying to make it constantly generate new answers from an array.
However, I can not define it properly because it is inside a function.
If I put the send inside the `random()` function, it will loop, which I do not want.
Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "8ball",
    description: "Ask something to the magic 8ball.",
    execute(msg, args){
        let question = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        
        if (!question){
          msg.channel.send("You need to ask the magic 8ball something, dude.");
          return;
        }       

      function random(){
        const answers = require("../data/8ball.json").answers;
        const chooseanswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
        return true;
      }
      setInterval(random, 3000);
      
      msg.channel.send("**You shake your 8ball and think hard, yet simple.**");
      msg.channel.send(`:8ball: You look into your 8ball and see "${chooseanswer}".`);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: This code won't work because chooseanswer is defined inside random(), and isn't available to the msg.channel.send. Perhaps you needed to call random() synchronously and return the value? But I'm not sure what you mean by "constantly generate new answers": you mean post a new answer to the channel every 3 seconds indefinitely? You need to send the message from inside your random() function I guess.

Comment: Now I figured it out, I needed to put it in the function then call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, you can use the return state to catch the selected answer. It will not modify the list and always return a different answer.
I have put the function outside of the module.exports function and put the answers require at the top of the file.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const answersList = require("../data/8ball.json").answers;

module.exports = {
    name: "8ball",
    description: "Ask something to the magic 8ball.",
    execute(msg, args){
        let question = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        
        if (!question){
          msg.channel.send("You need to ask the magic 8ball something, dude.");
          return;
        }       
      
      msg.channel.send("**You shake your 8ball and think hard, yet simple.**");
      msg.channel.send(":8ball: You look into your 8ball and see " + random(answersList) + ".");
       
    }
}

function random(answers){
  const chooseanswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
  return chooseanswer;
}
```